# ';' expected error ts(1005) in react js, why am i getting this error?

Tags: reactjs

This code is used to be a class component but I changed it to a functional component. But for some reason at this line after the bracket: `render() {` I get this error

> ';' expected error ts(1005)

What am I doing wrong in the code?

```
const Container = () =>
{
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost:5000/user") // could be any rest get url
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result =>
        this.setState({
          userData: result
        })
      );
    }, []);  
    
    

    changeColor = (params) => {
        this.setState({
            color: params.target.value
        })
    }

    changeSize = (params) => {
        this.setState({
            size: params.target.value
        })
    }
    
    render() {
        const dragUrl = React.useRef();
        const stageRef = React.useRef();
        const [images, setImages] = React.useState([]);
        return (
            
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="tools-section">
                            <div className="color-picker-container">
                                Select Brush Color : &nbsp; 
                                <input type="color" value={this.state.color} onChange={this.changeColor.bind(this)}/>
                            </div>

                            <div className="brushsize-container">
                                Select Brush Size : &nbsp; 
                                <select value={this.state.size} onChange={this.changeSize.bind(this)}>
                                    <option> 5 </option>
                                    <option> 10 </option>
                                    <option> 15 </option>
                                    <option> 20 </option>
                                    <option> 25 </option>
                                    <option> 30 </option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                
                        <div className="board-container">
                            
                            
                        
                            <h4>Select picture!</h4>
                        
                                
                                   
                              
                         
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody>
                                            {this.state.userData.map((data, key) => {
                                            return (
                                                
                                                <tr key={key}>
                                                 <img src={data.picture} class="img"  draggable="true"
                                                    onDragStart={(e) => {
                                                    dragUrl.current = e.target.src;
                                                    }}/> // column data received
                                                
                                                </tr>
                                            );
                                            })}
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>  
                             
                        
                            <div  onDrop={(e) => {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                // register event position
                                stageRef.current.setPointersPositions(e);
                                // add image
                                setImages(
                                    images.concat([
                                    {
                                        ...stageRef.current.getPointerPosition(),
                                        src: dragUrl.current,
                                    },
                                    ])
                                );
                                }}
                                onDragOver={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
                            ><Board color={this.state.color} size={this.state.size}></Board></div>
                            
                        </div>
                    
                    </div>
    
        );
    }

    
}



export default Container;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using Function component so it has not `render` method. Please remove it and use `return`.